# React Native Generating Signed APK "KeyStore file not set for signing config release"

Tags: gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I am trying to generate a signed APK. I have my password.keystore file located in \Dictionary\android\app and when i ran `gradlew assembleRelease` on cmd, the error:

Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

Keystore file not set for signing config release

Where should I store my password.keystore file? Because when I commented off the `if (project.hasProperty("password.keystore") {` it seems to work but with the following error instead:

Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)

How should I write my if condition or where should I store the password.keystore file?

The source code is as follows:

```
signingConfigs {
  release {
    if (project.hasProperty("password.keystore")) {
      storeFile file("password.keystore")
      storePassword "password"
      keyAlias "username"
      keyPassword "password"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to generate signed APK .. right?

Comment: @Codesingh Yes and it seems that `project.hasProperty("password.keystore")` returns false so when I excluded the if statement, the code runs. But I clearly have a file called password.keystore in \Dictionary\android\app.

Comment: once i was also struct in this part of app development then i started generating signed apk from build option at the top of the android studio window.

Answer (score 25):

The **keystore** file has to be in the **android/app** folder.

The message **'Keystore file not set for signing config release'** has to do that there is no signingConfig in the android/app/build.gradle file.

```js
buildTypes {
    release {
        // other settings
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

For testing you can just hard coded the settings in the android/app/build.gradle, instead off set it in the gradle.properties. This was fixing for me the problem with **'Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect'**

```js
  signingConfigs {
    release {
        //if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file("key.keystore")
            storePassword "****"
            keyAlias "myKey"
            keyPassword "****"
       // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommand this harcoded solutions, specially if you run out of time :)

Answer (score 22):

In my case, my project was on RN version 0.59 while I was using 0.60 RC documentation. So inside `app/build.gradle`

If version 0.59 :

`if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {`

If version 0.60 :

`if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {`

*The difference is the change from `RELEASE` to `UPLOAD`*

Comment: You saved my day, I had upgraded RN from 0.57 to 0.60 and lamely copied the old gradle.properties, and then I noticed the changes you mentioned, it solved my problem. Thank youl

Answer (score 16):

I have found a solution!

If you have followed [React Native's official instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html), just like me, you add following to your `gradle.properties`

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=<your-app>.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=<keystore-alias>
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=<password>
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=<password>
```

**And then comes the part that I totally misunderstood.**

In the `app/build.gradle`-file, you are *not* supposed to replace the strings. If your `gradle.properties` is like the one I pasted over, your `app/build.gradle` should look like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

What I originally did was replacing the strings (i.e. 'MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE' with the path to my keystore-file), but you are **not** supposed to replace any of the variables at all. I guess you could see the connection between the strings we created in `gradle.properties` and the release-config we have made in `app/build.gradle`.

Remember to have your `.keystore`-file inside `android/app` as well.

Answer (score 5):

I actually prefer to store these parameters outside the app repo using **environment variables** since it contains sensitive information like password, etc.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (System.env.MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE != null) {
            storeFile       file(System.env.MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword   System.env.MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias        System.env.MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword     System.env.MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Once this is done, I can just load up a bash script which has the details like

```
# path to my keystore
export MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=/path/to/key.file
# ...
```

This way the signing config is completely isolated from the repo. This prevents you from making accidental commits with your secrets.

Answer (score 4):

`project.hasProperty` will be looking in your `gradle.properties` file for a variable named password.keystore.

Go into `~/.gradle` and see if you have a `gradle.properties` file, if you do, make sure the variable `password.keystore` is there, it should point to your keystore file: `password.keystore=password.keystore`.

Although you should name it something different, like `MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=password.keystore`. Then when you run `./gradlew assembleRelease` your project will have the property it's looking for and the following will resolve true and allow gradlew to set all the signingConfigs.release properties:

```
if (project.hasProperty(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)) {
    storeFile file(...)
    storePassword your_password_property
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had exact same issue. Turn out I forgot to edit gradle.properties file. It should look like this:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me! We are on RN 59.3 not sure if that's relevant, never had this problem before, thank you so much for this help y'all!!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure alias name used in `gradle.properties` is same as the one used while creating `keystore` ( using `keytool` )

Answer (score 2):

the gradle.properties file i placed in android/gradle.properties  and it worked for me, looks like in latest react .gradle/gradle.properties file if we place it in this location it does not pick from their.

Comment: This resolved my problem. When I was using react-native 0.61, I place all the keystore variables in `android/.gradle/gradle.properties` and everything was fine. Now I switched to react-native 0.64, this no longer works. I have to place the keystore variables in `android/gradle.properties`.

Comment: @FanchenBao Great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After exploring all answers regarding this issue, none of the answer helped!

So tried  below experiment and it helped!!!!

Place the `my-release-key.keystore` file under the **android** directory in your project folder.

Comment: `my-release-key.keystore` means the path to the file or more specifically `./my-release-key.keystore`. It works from the android directory since that is the working directory of Gradle for that particular execution. You can hardcode an absolute path if you would like to

Answer (score 1):

Use ./gradlew bundleRelease than ./gradlew assembleRelease

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this :

```
           release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')
            storePassword 'MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD'
            keyAlias 'MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS'
            keyPassword 'MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have placed your **.keystore** file inside app folder and do gradle changes like below:

```
    signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case in my gradle.properties file was like

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=<your-app>.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=<keystore-alias>
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=<password>
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=<password>
```

and in my build.gradle file

```
release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
```

I was using *RELEASE* in my gradle.properties instead of *UPLOAD*. Just changed the *RELEASE* to *UPLOAD* in gradle.properties and issue was gone.